# How to stop VS Code from merging all attributes in one line?

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

In VS Code, I am using Prettier as autoformatter and I can't find an answer for this simple question.

If I have a manually written code like this - which I want it to stay like that on multiple lines:

```
createApp(App)
  .use(createPinia())
  .use(router)
  .mount("#app")
```

But after I press save, it will become:

```
createApp(App).use(createPinia()).use(router).mount("#app")
```

How to stop this behavior without turning autoformatting off completely? I still want to have the code to be corrected if the is 1 space instead of 2 before a html element etc.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of auto-formatting most surely relies on the Prettier's decision whether or not the code you wrap fits into one line if its maximum length equals `printWidth` (80 symbols default). In other words, two more `use`s and Prettier probably won't put your code in one line anymore.

This is the feature of Prettier which bothers a lot of developers, but as it's stated, for example, in [this issue](https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3468), we cannot turn the `printWidth`-based wrapping algorithm off. Alas.